# Importing TSV file from qualtrics into R raises error

Tags: r, csv

I'm not able to import a TSV survey data file in R due to an error (the file is exported from Qualtrics as TSV). This is my code:

```
library(readr)
df <- read_tsv('example_data_from_qualtrics.tsv')
```

Running the code results in this error message:

```
Error in vroom_(file, delim = delim %||% col_types$delim, col_names = col_names,  :          
  embedded nul in string: 'S\0t\0a\0r\0t\0D\0a\0t\0e'
```

Maybe an encoding issue. I couldn't find a solution yet.

EDIT: here's some sample data: https://ufile.io/9liydp15

Comment: Hard to help you without a sample of your file as a beginning

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I just couldn't figure out how to share sample data on stack overflow. I will try to find out an option to share sample data.

Comment: you just have to paste first lines of your file inside triple backticks in your post.

Comment: The data file has HUGE amount of columns, so it was not possible to even paste the header line. Therefore I edited my question and added a link to download sample data, i.e. https://ufile.io/9liydp15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the file. I think it's a bit strange file but with an encoding option (the file is UTF-16 with BOM), you can read it:

[image]
(see it in sublime text, notepad++).

```r
readr::read_tsv('~/Downloads/example_data_from_qualtrics.tsv', 
                locale = readr::locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE"))
```

I think it's better to delete lines 2 and 3 in your file before importing it. These lines could be read in another step to have label of your columns, for instance with readr::read_tsv(.., n_max = 2).

[image]

Then readr will guess column types more precisely.

[image]

To have answers by rows, you can pivot your data by user:

```
u <- readr::read_tsv('~/Downloads/example_data_from_qualtrics.tsv', locale = readr::locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE"))

v <- u %>% tidyr::gather(var, val, - IPAddress, - ResponseId, - UserLanguage, - DistributionChannel, 
                    - StartDate, - EndDate, - RecordedDate, 
                    - RecipientLastName, - RecipientFirstName, - RecipientEmail, - ExternalReference,
                    - Status, - Progress, - `Duration (in seconds)`, - Finished, - LocationLatitude, -LocationLongitude)
```

[image]

To have labels (and questions of the survey), you can do:

```r
u <- readr::read_tsv('~/Downloads/example_data_from_qualtrics.tsv', 
                     locale = readr::locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE"), n_max = 3)

v <- u %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1,3)) %>% 
  tidyr::gather(var, label_question)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, it's working flawlessly!